# Error on filter some extended property using calendar view

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an error when I try to run the following query in microsoft graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2018-08-09T13:30:00Z&endDateTime=2018-08-10T13:59:00Z&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {6b82adcb-38dc-46f4-9e83-ea5064740bf6} Name CheckedIn')&$filter=isCancelled eq false and singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {6b82adcb-38dc-46f4-9e83-ea5064740bf6} Name CheckedIn' and ep/value eq 'true')
```

Result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "49c4439a-f51d-444d-8862-488847cb1787",
            "date": "2018-08-10T13:15:03"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, we cannot add singleValueExtendedProperties to CalendarView, so the $expand=singleValueExtendedProperties will be ignore in the query. Because you use the $filter to filter the data again by a none-existing property, so the server encounter some unhandled exception.

Based on the docs, the singleValueExtendedProperties support the following resource:
message,mailFolder,event,calendar,contact,contactFolder,group event,group calendar,group post

Official docs for singleValueExtendedProperties: [Get](http://%20https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get) ; [Create](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_post_singlevalueextendedproperties)

You can submit an feature [request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or search similar request and then vote it.